# unique decomposition of representation

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $V$ be a complex representation of a finite group which is a direct sum of two nonismorphic irreducible representations  $V_1$ and $V_2$. If $V_3$ is another representation isomorphic to $V_1$, how can I show $V_1=V_3$ as vector spaces. thank you

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: @YiFan I can do it by projection,is that necessary? this statement appears as a direct result of Schur's lemma.

Comment: It would be good if you can add your attempts to the question body with an edit, along with the context in which the problem occurs. People react quite negatively to homework-like questions, so you want to prevent misunderstanding. Cheers!